# Calling C++ library in java using JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I have created a c++ lib for function given below

```
#include "Test.h" 
#include "iostream"      
extern "C" int add(int x,int y) {    
Add instance;
return instance.add(x,y);  
}
Add::Add()
{
std::cout<<"In Add Constructor::"<<std::endl;
}   
int Add::add(int x,int y) {
return x+y;  
}
```

then i used this library in another c++ and call its function.

```
#include "Test1.h"
#include "iostream"
Test1::Test1()
{
std::cout<<"InConstructor of Test1 Library::"<<std::endl;
int result = 0;
result = CallingLibFunction(10,20);
std::cout<<"SUM RESULT : "<<result<<std::endl;
}
extern "C" int CallingLibFunction(int x,int y) {

Test1 instance;
return instance.CallingLibFunction(x,y); 
} 
int Test1::CallingLibFunction(int x, int y)
{
int value = addFunc.add(x,y);
return value;
}
```

now i have created new library for Test1. and then use it in my jna example in java.

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
public class Test {
    static{
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/root/Desktop/Pragati/OSGI/JNA/JNAExample/JNASimpleExample/JNAApp/bin");
        System.out.println("java lib path : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        //System.loadLibrary("src");            
    }

    public interface Test1 extends Library
    {
        Test1 INSTANCE = (Test1) Native.loadLibrary("Test1", Test1.class);
        int CallingLibFunction(int x, int y);
    }
    //CallingLibFunction
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test1 lib = Test1.INSTANCE;
        System.out.println(lib.CallingLibFunction(10, 20));
    }
}
```

now this program encounter error that is given below:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /root/Desktop/Pragati/OSGI/JNA/JNAExample/JNASimpleExample/JNAApp/bin/libTest1.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3AddC1Ev
```

Comment: Try to create instance of your first library Add by loading it in your Test class before creating instance of Test1 library.
All libraries being referred should be loaded before any library referring them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
public class Test {
    static    {
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/root/Desktop/Pragati/OSGI/JNA/JNAExample/JNASimpleExample/JNAApp/bin");
    System.out.println("java lib path : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    //System.loadLibrary("src");            
}

public interface Test1 extends Library
{
   // Loading Referenced Libraries first
 Add ADD_INSTANCE = (Add) Native.loadLibrary("Add", Test.class);


    Test1 INSTANCE = (Test1) Native.loadLibrary("Test1", Test1.class);
    int CallingLibFunction(int x, int y);
}
//CallingLibFunction
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test1 lib = Test1.INSTANCE;
    System.out.println(lib.CallingLibFunction(10, 20));
}
}
```

Try this